# Knockout validation plugin and visible

Tags: validation, knockout.js, visible

Is there a way to say validation plugin to validate only field with ":visible" selector?
There are 2 blocks on form. And only one of them can be visible in one moment. For the invisible block i don't need validate the hidden data. Is it solution in validation plugin, such as in jQuery validation plugin?

> ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden"

Comment: knockout validation has a group functionality that you can use to create validation groups.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain your answer? I don't find it in samples.

Comment: It isn't an answer, it's a comment. It isn't in samples, but you can find it in the source code: `ko.validation.group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [danludwig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304832/danludwig). Using a  ko.validation.group() - is a answer. group is solve problem. I don't understand only, why this feature don't describe in docs.